# iOS App freezes at splash screen when user enables "Bold Text" on System Settings -> Display and Brightness

Tags: ios, splash-screen, freeze, bold, system-setting

My app freezes on the splash screen when "**Bold Text**" is enabled in System Settings -> Display and Brightness on iOS 13. 
If the app is installed on an **iPhone 11 there is no problem** but when the app is installed in a previous iPhone (X, XS, 8, 8S...) it freezes on splash screen and the only way to fix it is to:

1. **Close the app** from the **application switcher** if it is present
2. Go to **Settings -> Display and Brightness**
3. Turn off "**Bold Text**"
4. **Open the app** again.

XCode doesn't show me any crash or any other information when I debug my iPhone 6S or iPhone XS.

Can someone help me?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
When "Bold Text" was enabled in System Settings -> Display and Brightness on iOS 13, I was unable to set the frame of a view and this caused a loop in my app. I can't understand why this don't happen when bold text is disabled on the display and brightness system settings...

Comment: Same thing happening with me... Can you please tell me, how you solve this?